# How to replace chars in a string with other chars in a string using two input arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, translation

I have a string and want to replace all chars inside of an array of chars with the corresponding chars in an other array, how would I do that?

sample input/output:

```
translate("ㅎello") => "Hello"
```

with the following 2 arrays for translation

```
const from = ["ㅏ", "Б", "C", "Δ", "Э", "Ф", "Γ", "ㅎ", "И", "ㅈ", "ㅋ", "Λ", "ㅁ", "N", "Ω", "Π", "Q", "ㄹ", "Σ", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
const to = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
```

PS: this question was asked a few mins ago and was deleted before I was able to post my answer

Comment: Can you please add a sample input and output also?

Answer (score 0):

```
const from = ["ㅏ", "Б", "C", "Δ", "Э", "Ф", "Γ", "ㅎ", "И", "ㅈ", "ㅋ", "Λ", "ㅁ", "N", "Ω", "Π", "Q", "ㄹ", "Σ", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
const to = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

const translate = input => [...input].map(char => (index => ~index ? to[index] : char)(from.indexOf(char))).join("")
```

Comment: why not take an object for replacement?

Comment: the original answer asked for arrays, using an object would be better though

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping from input characters to output characters and then just get the corresponding value if the character exists in the mapping as a key:

```js
const from = ["ㅏ", "Б", "C", "Δ", "Э", "Ф", "Γ", "ㅎ", "И", "ㅈ", "ㅋ", "Λ", "ㅁ", "N", "Ω", "Π", "Q", "ㄹ", "Σ", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
const to = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
const mapping = new Map(from.map((c, i) => [c, to[i]]));

function translate(input) {
  return [...input].map(c => mapping.has(c) ? mapping.get(c) : c).join('');
}
console.log(translate("ㅎello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` and `replace`

```js
const from = ["ㅏ", "Б", "C", "Δ", "Э", "Ф", "Γ", "ㅎ", "И", "ㅈ", "ㅋ", "Λ", "ㅁ", "N", "Ω", "Π", "Q", "ㄹ", "Σ", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
const to = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
const mapper = new Map(from.map((key, index) => [key, to[index]]));

function translate(string) {
  return string.replace(/./gu, (g)=> mapper.get(g) || g)
}
console.log(translate("ㅎello"));
console.log(translate("ㅎellΠ"));
```